# Is it possible to delete rows using JDBC?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Using spark jdbc connection, I am able to either read or write data. For example:

```
app_project_model_df = (
  sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url",sqlURL)
  .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("dbtable","app.projectmodel")
  .option("user", dbuser)
  .option("password", dbpassword)
  .load()
)
```

However, is it possible to perform other SQL queries the very same way? Let's say `delete from app.projectmodel where key = 6`. Or do I need to use pure python for that?

I wasn't able to find any documentation on that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you need to delete only one row, or rows based on the content of dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Adding extra details over @thebluephantom's answer.

According to spark's jdbc docs ,

If you write a query / dbtable  -> `<user_specified_query>`

Then spark will run a query like :

```
SELECT <columns> FROM (<user_specified_query>) spark_gen_alias
```

One can fire any query that is supported by the DB's SQL Engine's `FROM` sub-query.
So, DELETE FROM is not supported within FROM.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless own implementation via forEachPartition for DF.